# Game has taken over my computer

Tags: windows-10, boot, gaming

I bought a Dragon Ball Z video game for my kid. We're running it on a Windows laptop. We couldn't figure out how to quit the game (there are zero instructions), so I got fed up and powered down the laptop.

Now, when it boots up, it goes straight into the game and we can't get out. This laptop is dead in the water.

First of all, how did this miserable piece of software get hooked into the Windows startup sequence? Second, how do we get it out and prevent it from ever getting that level of control again?

**Update**

More info, per the comment. The game is Dragon Ball Z Kakarot. I installed it via Steam. Yes, the game was playable. We just couldn't figure out how to get to the home screen and quit. I physically powered down the laptop with the on/off switch.

Ultimately, after I saw the comment ctrl-alt-delete did work. I went to task manager and tried to kill the process, but that failed. I went to log out user (or was it switch user?) and the system shut down the game task gracefully, which allowed me to reboot without the game taking over the startup process.

My question, though, stands: how do I prevent this game from running on startup, ever? This is strictly a Windows question, and has nothing to do with this specific game.

Comment: I'm afraid you're gonna have to be a bit more specific, about what game, where you bought it (was the game actually playable?), how did you power down the laptop? what steps did you take to try to shut down the game? (Did ctrl+alt+delte work?); also this is sounding quite a lot like a virus ;)

Comment: Make sure the computer is off. Hold down the Shift Key and press the power button. Start in Safe Mode and the uninstall the program. Use Programs and Features in Control Panel to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your computer isn't actually restarting, it's going to sleep and waking up with the game still running.

Press ALT+F4 (you may need to hold down the function key if you have one on the bottom row when you press F4) - This should quit the game.

If it doesn't, press CTRL+ALT+DELETE at the same time then find the game in the list you see then press end task.

This should let you back into your computer again, where you can remove the game from steam.

If this does not work, plugin the charger and hold down the power button for 10 seconds. wait another second, then press power again. This is known as a hard shutdown and should only be used in times like this. Plugging in the charger will set a different power mode which may not have the power button set to sleep.

Comment: Thanks. Alt-F4 is the best solution to the problem.

Answer (score 8):

When you pressed the power button, you did not “power down” (as in shut down) the system. Instead, you activated a power-saving mode that saves whatever you’re doing to disk so it can be restored even in the event of a power failure (like the battery running out).

When you turned the system back on, it may have appeared to be booting like normal, but it was in fact restoring the previously saved session, in which the game was running.

The game is not set to start automatically and will not do so.

If you truly want to stop the PC from doing whatever it is doing, you need to keep holding the power button until the system powers down. Only do this in emergency situations though, because it is the equivalent to yanking out the power cord in a regular desktop PC. It could damage whatever you’re currently working on. If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> helps, use that instead.

If you want to change what the power button does when you *do not* hold it down, go to “Power & sleep settings” in Windows, then on the right select “Additional power settings”. In the window that opens, select “Choose what the power buttons do” on the left. The available options should be relatively self-explanatory. Don’t forget to confirm your changes with “Save changes” at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 10, there are multiple places where items are added to startup.
If you launch the windows file explorer (the folder not internet explorer) and type in `shell:common startup` that will show you shortcuts that are added to launch on startup, you can delete these like you would a file.
Another place for startup items is in task manager (ctrl+shift+esc) under the startup tab, you can right click and hit disable to kill them.

Answer (score 1):

Your concern is about the automatic startup, "[H]ow do I prevent this game from running on startup."

Unless this is truly malicious software, malware , which needs to be removed with an effective malware removal tool, then there are a number of conventional locations used by Windows top run software at startup. To check all at once, use a tool such as Sysinternal's [Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns). Use *Search* or *Filter* to find instances with the game's name, or the game maker's name.

[image: Autoruns filtered on "xb"]

Uncheck the box, as shown for *XBox* game, to temporarily disable auto-start (safest), or right-click on an entry and select *Delete* to permanently remove it (risky, particularly if you've mistakenly chosen an essential Windows service).

**N.B.** The last column indicates a scan of the file at [VirusTotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/). *VirusTotal* is a service to check files for malware. You might upload the installer directly to *VirusTotal*, or the URL from which it can be obtained, to get the opinion of 50 or more antivirus tools. Occasionally, even valid software gets flagged by one, or perhaps two, as "malware", but I suggest removing anything that has more than a few flags! This is usually hard to do, once malware has been installed.